# Imagemagick import screenshot in Debian of a launched app

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen, imagemagick

I'd like to launch Iceweasel and then take a screenshot. When I simply try to wait and take it, it works fine

```
sleep 10;import -window root root/scr/scr.png
```

however when I first launch the browser, no screenshot is taken

```
iceweasel https://www.facebook.com/;sleep 10;import -window root root/scr/scr.png
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iceweasel` is not a daemon and thus won't put itself into the background. Therefore the `sleep 10` is only executed after `iceweasel` returns (i.e. after you closed it).

Instead put a `&` after your call to `iceweasel` in order to inform your shell that it should put the program into the background instead of waiting for it to return:

`iceweasel https://www.facebook.com/ & sleep 10;import -window root root/scr/scr.png`